# If H a subgroup, N normal in G and contains the commutators, does the intersection of H and N contain the commutators

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, H a subgroup, and $N \triangleleft G.$ I need to prove that if $G/N $ is abelian, then $H/(H\cap N)$ is abelian.

Let $G/N$ be abelian. Following a result from algebra, N then contains the commutator subgroup. It remains to be shown that $H\cap N$, which is a normal subgroup in $H,$ contains the commutator subgroup. Let $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in N $ with $x, y \in G.$ Since $(H\cap N)\triangleleft G, xhx^{-1}\in H\cap N, yh^{-1}y^{-1} \in H\cap N,$ with$\, x,y\in G,\, h\in (H\cap N).$ The product of these two elements does not give me the hint that the commutators are in $H\cap N.$

I dont know how to go further. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Going back and looking at the restriction of the standard homomorphism $\phi :G \to G/H$ to $H$ and its kernel might be easier.

Comment: I dont understand  the idea. So, let restrict the canonical homomorphism to $H$, $\phi_H : H \rightarrow G/H.$ Then $\forall h\in H, \phi_H(h)=H.$ Where do I find the commutators here ?

Comment: The idea is that the image of $H$ is abelian because it is a subgroup of $G/H$ and, since the kernel of the restricted homomorphism is $H\cap N$, the image is isomorphic with $H/(H\cap N)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: all the commutators in $H$ as a group are also in $N$ (because they are also commutators in $G$)

Comment: So, the subgroup of commutators is contained in all subgroups of G ?

Comment: In other words. Since $G/N$ is abelian then $N$ contains all the commutators of $G$, in particular those of $H\leq G$.

Comment: @user249018 The group generated by commutators of $H$ is contained in the group generated by commutators of $G$

Comment: @Mark Bennet. Thanks. But still I dont get to the point I need. I need to show that  $H\cap N$ contains all elements $aba^{-1}b^{-1}, \,a,b \in H.$ Since $N$ contains all elements $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}, \,x,y \in G$ (because $G/N$ is assumed abelian) one must show that the set of the commutators in $H$ is contained in the set of the commutators in $N$. Can we claim that the set of the  commutators in $G$ is equal to the set of the commutators in $N$ ?

Comment: @user249018 I meant this as a hint. If $G/N$ is abelian, $N$ contains the commutator subgroup of $G$, and hence contains all the commutators. The commutators in $H$ are also in $N$ (because they are in $G$ and all the ones on $G$ are in $N$) and hence in $H\cap N$, which therefore contains the commutator subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second isomorphism theorem $HN/N \cong H/(H\cap N)$ combined with the fact that subgroups of abelian groups are also abelian.